# r correlation control for pre-test differences

Tags: r, correlation

This seems pretty straight forward - I'm most likely not thinking of the right terms.

I have two groups. They show a correlation between group and pre-test scores.

I would like to control for this initial difference among pre-test scores when looking at correlations between group and post test(s).

How do I do this in r?

Answer (score 1):

```
 model <- lm(post ~ pre + grp, data=dat)
```

This is really the simplest case of a repeated measures design and has over the year generated a lot of statistical comment and opinion. I did attempt locating an earlier SO posting but didn't succeed in two attempts so just posted the answer. You may want to go to stats.stackexchange.com and search on pre-post with regression or ANOVA.

Comment: Thank you. Looks good. I apologize on not being sure - so the correlation between post score and group (with pre-test variance controlled for) is .03?

(intercept) - 0.59   pre -0.3          group 0.03

Comment: ? BTW this isn't a homework assignment. I'm trying to use r in contrast to everyone around me using spss.

Comment: Those are not correlation coefficients. They are estimated effects on the measurement scale of scores.

Comment: How might I find the correlation coefficients? I had looked at the aov - I was wondering how to move from that to correlation coefficients.

Comment: I would think it would be right there. My search also turned up a lot of basic correlation questions (97 pages) but not that little bit.

Comment: You do not want correlation coefficients. (Or if you really do, you will need to explain what you are doing and why you do not want estimates of effects.)